# Можно ли как то редактировать invoce`ы на оплату в aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

Я бы хотел, чтобы в данном хендлере после удачной оплаты, аргумент description в invoice - сообщении редактировался('неоплачено' поменалось на 'оплчачено'). Можно ли как то это сделать?
Метод edit_message_text выдает ошибку 'aiogram.utils.exceptions.MessageCantBeEdited: Message can't be edited'

```
@dp.message_handler(lambda message:message["successful_payment"]["invoice_payload"] == "invoice-record", content_types=ContentType.SUCCESSFUL_PAYMENT)
async def successful_payment_record(_):
    mess_u = CLIENT_MESSAGE_['invoice']['description'] # получение текста старого сообщения для редактирования
    mess_m = MASTER_MESSAGE_['text'] # получение текста старого сообщения для редактирования
    mess_u = mess_u.replace('<b>Неоплачено</b>', '<b>Оплачено</b>') # редактирование
    mess_m = mess_m.replace('<b>Неоплачено</b>', '<b>Оплачено</b>') # редактирование
    await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=CLIENT, message_id=CLIENT_MESSAGE_['message_id'], text=mess_u)
    await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=MASTER, message_id=MASTER_MESSAGE_['message_id'], text=mess_m, parse_mode='HTML')
```